# How to keep mainactivity alive when i close other activity from the recent task list?

Tags: android

After Android crosses the task of the child process from the recent task list, the main process task is also closed, how can i keep alive?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent activity from being destroyed as long as possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22168287/prevent-activity-from-being-destroyed-as-long-as-possible)

Comment: No, there are two activities, which one was launched bg Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT and Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK.When we open recentList and close the second, the main activity was destroy too. This will happen in some of Android phone.

Comment: how about adding 1 more flag `android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RETAIN_IN_RECENTS`, did it works retaining your main activity? This is suggested in https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/recents#retain-finished

Answer (score 0):

Use a service instead...

> A service is a general-purpose entry point for keeping an app running in the background for all kinds of reasons. It is a component that runs in the background to perform long-running operations or to perform work for remote processes.

Learn more about [Basics of Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks, but it is not the solution of my question. Suppose there are two activities, which one was launched bg Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT and Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK.When we open recentList and close the second activity, the main activity was destroy too. This will happen in some of Android phone.